# Help solving a trig equation involving secants, cosecants, cotangents, and tangents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If I’m given $$\sec(x)\tan(x)-\csc(x)\cot(x)=0$$ in the domain $\left(0,\frac{π}{2}\right)$, how would I algebraically find the value of $x$? I know the answer is $\frac{π}{4}$ because that’s where sine and cosine are equal, but algebraically, how would I properly find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be as follows:

$$\sec x \tan x = \csc x \cot x $$
$$\frac{1}{\cos x}\cdot \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{1}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} $$
$$\sin ^3 x = \cos ^3x $$
$$\tan^3x=1$$
$$(\tan x - 1)(\tan^2 x + \tan x + 1)=0$$

The real root of the above equation gives $\tan x = 1 = \tan \frac{\pi}{4}$.
The other 2 roots are complex where $$\tan x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4}}{2}=\omega,\omega^2 \Rightarrow x = \tan^{-1}(\omega),\tan^{-1}(\omega^2) $$

So we have $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

$csc(x)cot(x)=sec(x)tan(x) \Rightarrow \frac{cos(x)}{sin^{2}(x)}=\frac{sin(x)}{cos^{2}(x)} \Rightarrow  cos^{3}(x)=sin^{3}(x)\Rightarrow  tan^{3}(x)=1 \Rightarrow  tan(x)=1\Rightarrow  x=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning
$$\sec (x) \tan (x) - \csc (x) \cot (x) = 0 \implies \frac{\sin (x)}{\cos ^2(x)}=\frac{\cos (x)}{\sin ^2(x)}.$$

As $x \in (0,\pi/2)$, $0<\cos(x)<1$ and $0<\sin(x)<1$, which yields
$$\sqrt[3]{\sin^3 (x)} = \sqrt[3]{\cos^3 (x)} \implies \sin (x) = \cos (x).$$ And that is how you got your answer. But if it didn't satisfy you, use their exponential forms, and you have

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \left( e^{+i x}+ e^{-i x} \right) &= \frac{1}{2 i} \left( e^{+i x} - e^{-i x} \right) \\
i \left(e^{+i \theta }+e^{-i \theta }\right) &= \left(e^{+i \theta} -e^{-i \theta }\right) \\
(1+i) e^{-i \theta}       &= (1-i) e^{+i \theta} \\
e^{-2 i \theta}        &= \frac{1-i}{1+i} \\
e^{-2 i \theta }        &= -i\\
e^{-2 i \theta }        &= e^{\frac{3\pi}{2} i}\\
\end{align}

The solutions have clearly the form $$\theta = \frac{3\pi}{4} + k \pi \qquad \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, $$ and the solution in our domain is given by $k=-1$, hence $$\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sec(x)\tan(x)-\cot(x)\csc(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\tan(x)\left(\cot^2(x)\csc(x)-\sec(x)\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\tan(x)\left(\cot^2(x)\csc(x)-\sec(x)\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\tan(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space \cot^2(x)\csc(x)-\sec(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\pi n\space\space\vee\space\space \cot^3(x)=1$$

With $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

(short hand for trig)

$$\sec x \tan x = \csc x \cot x $$

$$\frac{1}{c}\cdot \frac{s}{c} = \frac{1}{s}\cdot \frac{c}{s} $$

$$s^3  = c^3, t^3 =1 $$

$$ t = 1, x \rightarrow ( 2 k -1) \pi/2 , k=0,1,2,3... $$

Three complex cube roots of unity for $$ t^2 +t +1=0 $$

placed at $$ x= \pm \pi/3, \pm \pi $$ on Argand/Gauss diagram.